# Apache application/octet-stream create an empty file

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xamarin, multipartform-data

I try to upload a file to a server using a Xamarin.Forms application.

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(img)), "file", "image.jpg");
httpClient.PostAsync(uri, MultipartFormDataContent);
```

I receive the file on the server using PHP and the Symfony UploadedFile class.
This part works well on my localhost (`macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1` / `Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)`) when I do my testings I am able to receive the file:

```
"file" => UploadedFile {#217 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "image.jpg"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 8112955
    -error: 0
    path: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php"
    filename: "phpWyUBHM"
    basename: "phpWyUBHM"
    pathname: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpWyUBHM"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpWyUBHM"
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
```

Apache config:

```
upload_max_filesize 32M 32M
post_max_size       32M 32M
```

So I'm able to move the file and it's the actual image i uploaded.

When I try to do it on my demo server (`Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` / `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`) the received file is actually empty, the size of it is 0

```
"file" => UploadedFile {#217 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "image.jpg"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 0
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phppFr9Pr"
    basename: "phppFr9Pr"
    pathname: "/tmp/phppFr9Pr"
    extension: ""
    realPath: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
```

Apache config:

```
upload_max_filesize 1000M   1000M
post_max_size       1000M   1000M
```

So I guess the problem come from Apache but i've been searching for a long time now and couldn't find any hints to solve this issue.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT 1**

The permissions of the /tmp directory are:

```
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 4096 Nov 15 14:19
```

If I try to post an image with Postman, the `/tmp` directory is well created:

```
"file" => UploadedFile {#217
    -test: false
    -originalName: "image.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 8112955
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php2LIEcm"
    basename: "php2LIEcm"
    pathname: "/tmp/php2LIEcm"
    extension: ""
    realPath: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
```

So it means apache and php have the permissions to write in this `/tmp` directory.

Comment: Can you show us the file permissions of the folder?

Comment: Hi @Ronald, i've edited my question, Apache and PHP can actually write files in `/tmp`

Comment: Are you sure? Why is it that the user and user-group is still "root root"?

Comment: Yes, I was able to upload a file using Postman, the temporary file has been saved in `/tmp` and using my php script I copied the file from `/tmp` to `/tmp` but with a new name so it must be ok if my php script can write a file in the directory.

Comment: @Ronald, I tried to change the owner and group to `drwxrwxrwt  13 www-data www-data  4096 Nov 15 16:43 tmp/` and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the permissions of `/tmp`. The user (like Apache or php) that executes your script should have permissions to `write` to `/tmp` and `read` from.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question, Apache and PHP can actually write files in `/tmp`